# Pronunciation of "Gerber"

Tags: pcb

How is "Gerber" pronounced? By "gerber" I am referring to the type/class of files generated for PCB manufacturing. I could imagine the first "g" being pronounced with a "g" as in "girl", or a "j" as in "jerk".

Comment: Gerber like the Gerber baby

Comment: I always thought it's Gerber like good, but can't find an official reference right now...

Comment: G like girl, gantry, great. There's no jiff/gif controversy here.

Comment: It's just an Austrian name... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsOiTnV6pnw

Comment: @PeterJ I've lost confidence in those [YouTube pronunciation links](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHTxzn4YL6o)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with electronic design.

Comment: @LeonHeller I would disagree, as I am designing a PCB and working to get it assembled, and would like to know how to properly discuss the file types, eg. with the fab house. I think that is very relevant to electrical engineering.

Comment: This is a topic which has something to with electronic design. (Topics which have something *to do with* electronic design aren't themselves electronic design.)

Comment: Proper pronunciation rhymes with "her" (twice).

Comment: Questions about toolchains are on topic as far as I know.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe it is based on the original plotter file format for machines made by [Gerber Technology](http://www.gerbertechnology.com/)  I had a friend that worked there for a while and they pronounced the name of  the company exactly like the baby food as Matt says, Grrr Brrr like you're growling at someone but also chilly :)

Joseph Gerber was an Austrian, hence it is a German name. There is no "g" pronounced as "jerk" in the German language, it is always like "girl".

Comment: Thanks! I'll just imagine being a polar bear when I'm saying it.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerber_format#History) disagrees about the company. But anyway, since his name was pronounced Gare-bare (say it fast) before he migrated, I don't think it would be anglicized as "Jerber".

Comment: Ah I wanted to say it was gerber scientific but when I searched for it I came up with gerber tech.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard it pronounced like the baby food. In IPA, I think it's something like /gɚbɚ/. The "er" is the same sound as the second syllable in "dinner", at least in American English.